# Odd Scala ClassCastException

Tags: scala, exception, casting

The following code compiles, but throws an exception on the last line. Why is this? How can I avoid it? (The code below is contrived to show the problem; I do need to do something similar in actual code.)

```
type F = Int => Int

val f: Int => Int = identity
val g1: F => F = identity
val g2: F => F = (identity _).asInstanceOf[F => F]

println("f = " + f)
println("g1 = " + g1)
println("g2 = " + g2)

val h1: Int => Int = g1(f: Int => Int)
val h2: Int => Int = g2(f: Int => Int)
```

Here is the output of the code:

```
f = doodle.Bug$$$Lambda$7/1836797772@4b53f538
g1 = doodle.Bug$$$Lambda$8/1383547042@543e710e
g2 = doodle.Bug$$$Lambda$9/3213500@57f23557
```

Here is the exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: doodle.Bug$$$Lambda$7/1836797772 cannot be cast to scala.runtime.Nothing$
```

I find it particularly strange that casting `g2` results in an implicit cast on `f`...

Comment: `asInstanceOf` in fact does nothing here due to type erasure . It checks only that `g2` is of type `Function1` but doesn't guarantee that the type parameters match. I guess that there are compiler warnings for this code.

Comment: @simpadjo There are no compiler warnings. I agree with you, `asInstanceOf` shouldn't do anything there. However, the line defining `h1` runs fine, while the one for `h2` doesn't. So it seems to do something after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wild guess: ammonite suggest that this:

```
(identity _)
```

has a type of:

```
Nothing => Nothing
```

Scala might remember this fact. Maybe because of specialization or (more likely) maybe Eta expansion of `identity` creates a closure that remember that it IS `Nothing => Nothing` function that underneath call `identity`.

In such situation, when you use it in context where JVM does an actual check (so not at the moment you run `asInstanceOf`, but during the application), then casting fails and you see the exception.

```
identity[F] _
```

works as expected without exception.

Comment: Nice! So it looks like it's better to avoid `(m _)` altogether, and use `(m: A => B)` instead.